# saving references to other entities

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc application using hibernate over a MySQL database, I have a `Document` entity with each `document` object containing different types of `codes` that are all instances of a `Code` entity.  The `Code` entity contains a distinct list of possible values that are defined by a combination of `code.pk.code` and `code.pk.codesystem`, with `pk` being a reference to a composite primary key.  And each `code` object might be referenced by many `document` objects.

**How do I map this in hibernate and MySQL?**

The way I have things laid out now, I keep getting errors about violating primary key constraints for `Code` every time I try to store a `Document` containing any `code` that is already stored in the `codes` table of the underlying MySQL database.  Specifically, when my dao runs the following line of code:

```
this.entitymanager.persist(document)
```

The following error is immediately thrown:

```
Hibernate: insert into codes (displayname, code, codesystem) values (?, ?, ?)
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'somecode-somecodesystem' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The program crashes at that point, so I don't know if it would otherwise next save the `document` to the `documents` table in the database.  Why **does it try to save to the `codes` table?  Is there some way I can set things up so that it just saves the references to the `code` to the `documents` table?**  It would be a nuisance to remove the relationship and just store the keys as strings in the `documents` table without joining `codes` to `document`.

Here is my java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "confidentiality_code", referencedColumnName = "code"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "confidentiality_codesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem"),
})
public Code conftype;

//other stuff, then getters and setters  
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "codes")
public class Code implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
public EmbedCodePK codePk;

@Column(name="displayname")
private String displayname;

public EmbedCodePK getCodePk(){return codePk;} 
public void setCodePk(EmbedCodePK mypk){codePk = mypk;}

public String getDisplayname(){return displayname;}
public void setDisplayname(String dspnm){displayname=dspnm;}

}

@Embeddable
public class EmbedCodePK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 652312726451130179L;

@Column(name="code", nullable=false)
public String code;

@Column(name="codesystem", nullable=false)
private String codesystem;

public EmbedCodePK() {}
public EmbedCodePK(String c, String cs) {
    this.code = c;
    this.codesystem = cs;
}

/** getters and setters **/
public String getCode(){return code;}
public void setCode(String c){code=c;}

public void setCodesystem(String cs) {this.codesystem = cs;}
public String getCodesystem() {return codesystem;}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    final EmbedCodePK other = (EmbedCodePK) obj;
    if (code == null) {
        if (other.code != null) return false;
    } else if (!code.equals(other.code)) return false;
    if (codesystem == null) {
        if (other.codesystem != null) return false;
    } else if (!codesystem.equals(other.codesystem)) return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() { 
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + ((code == null) ? 0 : code.hashCode());
    hash = 53 * hash + ((codesystem == null) ? 0 : codesystem.hashCode());
    return hash;
}
}
```

Comment: Spring is unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the `CascadeType.ALL` from the `ManyToOne` relationship, so that it now looks as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "confidentiality_code", referencedColumnName = "code"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "confidentiality_codesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem"),
})
public Code conftype;
```

This problem has now been successfully resolved.  Question answered.